# How to retain data even after app is closed in windows phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7

In my app i'm having two variables, which i want to retain even after my application is closed.
Which would be the right way to accompolish it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of different storages available on Windows Phone 7.x as well as Windows Phone 8

If these two values of yours are settings, you want to preserve, I recommend you to use the IsolatedStorageSettings. This is a simple key / value store to save and load variables after restart your app. See the the following sample of MSDN ([How to create settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff769510%28v=vs.105%29.aspx))

See a list of other API's and samples on when and how to use it here ([Data for Windows Phone on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402541%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_Localfolder))

Answer (score 2):

You can store the values in an `IsolatedStorage`. There is a very nice article on MSDN regarding the persistance of information on Windows Phone. You can read it here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg680266(v=pandp.11).aspx

The example shown by Microsoft looks something like this:

```
private const string CAR_PHOTO_FILE_NAME = "CarPhoto.jpg";
private const string CAR_KEY = "FuelTracker.Car";
private static readonly IsolatedStorageSettings appSettings =
    IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;

public static void SaveCar(Action errorCallback)
{
    try
    {
        appSettings[CAR_KEY] = Car;
        appSettings.Save();
        DeleteTempCarPhoto();
        SaveCarPhoto(CAR_PHOTO_FILE_NAME, Car.Picture, errorCallback);
        NotifyCarUpdated();
    }
    catch (IsolatedStorageException)
    {
        errorCallback();
    }
}
```

The process of reading the information is very much the same. Go through the article and adopt it for your own needs.